# Why does list comprehension in my Python Interactive shell append a list of Nones?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-interactive

I'm testing some Django functionality in my interactive shell

Here's my attempt to probe these objects, note the list of Nones at the end

```
>>> [print(foo) for foo in CharacterSkillLink.objects.all() if foo.speciality]
Streetwise (Street Countdown) Roran
[None]
```

And with a more orthodox list comprehension:

```
>>> [print(foo) for foo in range(1,10)]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Nine Nones, all in a row.

Why am I getting that?

Comment: Because `print()` returns None

Comment: [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

Comment: Since everybody already said why it's behaving like that, I'll hint how to print it: `print('\n'.join([str(foo) for foo in range(1,10)]))`

Comment: @IgorHatarist Or simply: `print(*range(10), sep='\n')`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yup, unpacking a range would be more appropriate given py3k :) I just showed how to do it with a list comprehension

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thanks for those nuggets of information, in the python world, I'd barely call myself a milk snake.

Comment: @IgorHatarist but I'm guessing I couldn't unpack a range with an `if` statement in there, right?

Comment: @Pureferret Right. You can use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) for that, but it'll grow quickly and will look pretty ugly. Ashwini has provided a great relevant question about side effects :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `print` returns a value, namely `None`. What it prints and what it returns are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, you use Python 3.x, in which print **function** returns None after printing to the console and thus you are getting this output. Whereas, if you have used Python 2.x, you will correctly get a SyntaxError for the print function.

A better example will be this(in python 2.x as your example wont work in python 2.x)

```
>>> b = []
>>> [b.append(i) for i in range(10)]
...[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> print b
...[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you wish to print things AND add it to the list, it should be like this:

```
[(print(foo) or foo) for foo in CharacterSkillLink.objects.all() if foo.speciality]
```

However, in my view, refrain from using such things as things might get ugly after some period of time.

Comment: It's not a statement anymore, it is a function now.(Python 3)

Comment: My bad :-) will change the answer to reflect that :-D